# Recently registered .st domain name, why is my domain not redirecting to my webserver?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, a-record

I am having quite a bit of trouble getting my domain name (which is .st) to redirect to my web server on Amazon EC2.

I have added an A record in my DNS advanced settings through the web console of my registrar. It's an A record that points to my Amazon Elastic IP which is attached to my amazon EC2 instance. Visiting this elastic IP in my browser does in fact send me to my website.

The primary DNS server is ns1.nic.st. (Assigned by the web-console when I choose to add an A-record).
I assume this means that I am adding an a-record on my registrar's own DNS server.

nslookup and ping tell me that the dns server is alive.

```
~$nslookup ns1.nic.st

Server:         172.16.0.23
Address:        172.16.0.23#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ns1.nic.st
Address: 195.178.160.40
```

but nslookup on my domain name gives me a 'cant find' error:

```
~$nslookup upmo.st
Server:         172.16.0.23
Address:        172.16.0.23#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find upmo.st: No answer
```

It has been 24 hours since I added this A record, does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Give us the real domain name to check for ourselves.

Comment: What @womble said.  There's no need to hide/disguise domain names.  They're public anyway.  I don't even believe in hiding/obscuring IP addresses.  I mean, I could guess your ip in 255^255^255^255 tries.

Comment: Alright, edited.

Comment: @JeffG: Use a real resolver... that IP address reverses to `hit-nxdomain.opendns.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Squish](http://www.squish.net/dnscheck/v1.html) sez:

> 62.5% of queries will end in failure at 195.178.160.2 (ns1.bahnhof.net) - no such record
>
> 37.5% of queries will end in failure at 195.178.160.40 (ns1.nic.st) - no such record

So, whoever's holding your DNS records (bahnhof.net, nic.st) isn't actually serving those records.  Best to get in contact with them to fix that up, or else move your DNS hosting to a provider that works.

Comment: Do you think waiting another 24 hours will cause the record to appear? Just wondering if bahnhof.net is actually at fault here

Comment: If it does, I'd be moving DNS providers *immediately* -- a new record should show up within seconds.